# Reading and writing properties with GCD in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm reading one of the items in effective Objective-C, and the author has this example:

```
_syncQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

- (NSString *)someString {
  __block NSString *localSomeString;
  dispatch_sync(_syncQueue, ^{
    localSomeString = _someString;
  });
  return localSomeString;
}

- (void)setSomeString:(NSString *)someString {
  dispatch_barrier_async(_syncQueue, ^{
    _someString = someString;
  });
}
```

I wanted some help in understanding this code.

1) Do you have to use dispatch_sync in the getter because if you used dispatch_async, the async nature would then return localSomeString right away without ever executing the dispatch_sync block.

2) Since the barrier is being using and protecting that _someString from being altered by other threads, you don't need to use dispatch_barrier_sync?

Comment: Moreover, the usage of `dispatch_barrier_async()` on a global queue is meaningless. It is simply `dispatch_async()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, correct. Using `dispatch_barrier_async` would cause the getter to return the uninitialized `localSomeString`.
2. The setter can use `dispatch_barrier_async` because the caller doesn't need to wait for the setter to complete the actual setting of the ivar before returning. Any read requests made after this will block until the write gets its chance to run.

Comment: I don't think that the barrier_async() is risky?  In a concurrent queue, it should block execution of any newly enqueued blocks until the barrier block is executed.  Thus, any reader blocks enqueued after the barrier block is scheduled will block on the barrier.  async() executes asynchronously, but enqueuing is still atomic.

Comment: @bbum I believe you are right. I was thinking, probably incorrectly, that if there were other read accesses going on when the write access happened, that another read access could sneak in before the write access ran. But I believe you are correct, that other read will get queued to run after the write gets its chance. I'll update my answer.